# Passar uma variável como parâmetro, e não o valor dela

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código, e na função de mudança, eu quero passar uma variável como parâmetro, e não o valor dela, e não sei como fazer isso. Porque quero que a função faça o "listen" da variável, e não do valor dela, assim quando eu atribuir um novo valor a variável status, o evento de mudança será disparado.

```
let status = true;

function onChange(value, callback) {
    let aux = value;
    setInterval(() => {
        if(value != aux) {
            aux = value;
            callback();
        }
    }, 100)
}
onChange(status, () => {
    console.log('Valor Mudou');
});
status = false;
//a saída ira disparar o evento de mudança, percebendo que a variável status agora é falsa, entretanto isso não acontece pois ele está pegando o valor dela, e não a variável em si.
```

Comment: Você não poderia simplesmente utilizar get/set?

Comment: @Francisco, get/set resolveria de fato, mas aí precisaria rescrever todos os atributos que quero fazer o listen, criando seus getters e setters. E não queria ter que reescrever, por isso estou tentando fazer algo mais genérico, não sei se é possível, mas seria isso.

Comment: Acho que as únicas formas de fazer isso que quer é com [_getters_ e _setter_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) ou com [_Proxy_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: Se você só tiver objetos, você consegue sim passar seu valor com a referencia do objeto original. Dai você conseguiria implementar a solução que está na pergunta.

Comment: Sim @Francisco, o problema é que estou fazendo isso para um código extenso e antigo, eu teria que rescrever todas as variáveis, os métodos que usam essas variáveis, e por aí vai. Teria que transformá-los em objeto, criar get/set. No fim isso vai aumentar o meu trabalho, dessa forma, eu faria um listen especifico para cada variável: statusOnChange() e lá dentro iria dizer que quero verificar o valor da variável status, no entanto como eu disse, queria fazer algo mais genérico, que pudesse ser reaproveitado. Pela quantidade de código, no momento get/set não vai me ajudar. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A única maneira de fazer isso é com um *setter*. Assim quando o valor mudar a `callback` vai ser corrida de novo. Isso é o que está por trás da reactividade do Vue.js por exemplo.

Deixo um exemplo. A ideia é ter getters/setters *à lá* ES6 e ter uma array onde guardas as callbacks para uma dada variável/nome. Não dá para usar variáveis diretamentes porque em JavaScript não é possível, mas propriedades de um objeto já dá usando os tais getters/setters.

```js
const reactors = {}; // arrays de callbacks
const reactivos = {}; // as variáveis que vais mudar
const store = {}; // onde guardas os valores reais, isto seria uma propriedade privada de uma classe. Ou seja não deves mudar diretamente aqui, só via setter.

// define o getter/setter para "status"
function registarNome(nome, init) {
  store[nome] = init;
  if (!reactors[nome]) {
    reactors[nome] = [];
  }
  
  Object.defineProperty(reactivos, nome, {
    get() {
      return store[nome];
    },
    set(val) {
      store[nome] = val;
      reactors[nome].forEach(fn => fn(val));
    }
  });
}

// registar e inicialisar a variável
registarNome('status', true);


function onChange(nome, callback) {
  reactors[nome].push(callback);
}

// registar o auscultador de mudanças
onChange('status', (val) => {
  console.log('Valor mudou para ', val);
});

// mudanças que vão chamar a callback
reactivos.status = false;
reactivos.status = true;
```